# 28 BYJ stepper motor runs faster using delay() and little slower using millis(), why?

Tags: code-optimization, speed, stepper-motor

I'm working to develop a code for the stepper motor to use it in a project. And since using delay() isn't as efficient as millis(). So I first developed the code that use delay with 1ms delay between the steps which is the fastest I could do with this stepper motor.

Then I developed similar code using millis() with same 1ms delay but it didn't feel as smooth/fast as the one with delay() function.

So what's the reason for that?

These are the code:

1. With delay():

   ```
       void clockwise(void){
           digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
       delay(1);
           digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
       delay(1);  
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
       delay(1);    
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
       delay(1);
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
       delay(1);    
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
       delay(1);      
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
       delay(1);        
           digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
       delay(1);   
   }
   ```
2. With millis():

   ```
     void stepper_run_cw(void){
     stepper_step_cw(1,0,0,0,1);
     stepper_step_cw(1,1,0,0,1);
     stepper_step_cw(0,1,0,0,1);
     stepper_step_cw(0,1,1,0,1);
     stepper_step_cw(0,0,1,0,1);
     stepper_step_cw(0,0,1,1,1);
     stepper_step_cw(0,0,0,1,1);
     stepper_step_cw(1,0,0,1,1);  
   }


   void stepper_step_cw(uint8_t m_in1, uint8_t m_in2, uint8_t m_in3, uint8_t m_in4, uint8_t delay_time){
     if (!stepper_run){
       digitalWrite(in1, m_in1);
       digitalWrite(in2, m_in2);
       digitalWrite(in3, m_in3);
       digitalWrite(in4, m_in4);
       stepper_start = millis();
       stepper_run = 1;
     }

     if(stepper_run){
       stepper_current = millis();
       if(stepper_current - stepper_start >= delay_time){
         stepper_run = 0;
       }    
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: why would you repeat `digitalWrite(in1, LOW);` five times in a row? .... you only need to run it one time  .... same for the other pins   ........... also, the `if(stepper_run){` should be an `else` instead

Comment: @jsotola 1. How to run it one time? And in which function? The 1st or 2nd posted codes? 2. Got the tip about using `else` thanks.

Comment: How can the second function work at all? What if you enter in stepper_run_cw with stepper_run = 0 and millis not changing , nothing? stepper_step_cw call that does something is purely random, the one where millis changed form the last call to stepper_step_cw.

Comment: try using micros() instead of millis()

Comment: i just had a thought ..... i wonder if the order of the `digitalWrite` commands has anything to do with the speed difference .... one is 4321 and the other is 1234 ................ change the order in one of them ....... also put `stepper_start = millis();` at the top of the `if` block

Comment: @jsotola yep the `micros()` works too, I can crank the speed even faster :) thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for the second function you want something like this:

```
 void stepper_run_cw(void){
  stepper_step_cw(1,0,0,0,1);
  stepper_step_cw(1,1,0,0,1);
  stepper_step_cw(0,1,0,0,1);
  stepper_step_cw(0,1,1,0,1);
  stepper_step_cw(0,0,1,0,1);
  stepper_step_cw(0,0,1,1,1);
  stepper_step_cw(0,0,0,1,1);
  stepper_step_cw(1,0,0,1,1);  
}


void stepper_step_cw(uint8_t m_in1, uint8_t m_in2, uint8_t m_in3, uint8_t m_in4, uint8_t delay_time){
  unsigned long temp, i;
  for (i=0;i<delay_time;i++){
    temp = millis();
    while (temp == millis){};//wait for millis to change 
  }
    digitalWrite(in1, m_in1);
    digitalWrite(in2, m_in2);
    digitalWrite(in3, m_in3);
    digitalWrite(in4, m_in4);
}
```

This code is also avoiding the millis overflow issue if you run your board for a long time.

Still, apart for a improved timing, there is no gain in using millis(), you still have to wait for millis to change, you might want to use a timer interrupt to do the job in background.

Comment: The real gain when using `millis()` is that you aren't blocked in `delay()` and can react to inputs changing without needing to resort to interrupts.

Comment: Yes, that's my aim. Is not to use `delay`. Hmm I'm still considering to improve the function which uses `millis()`, it's working anyway, it just give a different result like littttle slower that's all. Otherwise it's works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

After working on developing the function couple times, I got a way with this function and runs smoothly too :)

Hope anyone find it useful.

```
// this library is for the 28BYJ stepper motor

  #define in1 6
  #define in2 7
  #define in3 8
  #define in4 9

  // blink
  unsigned long blink_start_millis;
  unsigned long blink_current_millis;
  unsigned long blink_period = 100;

  uint8_t stepper_masks[] = {0x80,0xc0,0x40,0x60,0x20,0x30,0x10,0x90};
  int8_t s=0;
  uint32_t stepper_start;
  uint32_t stepper_current;
  uint32_t stepper_period;
  byte stepper_run;

  void blink_pin13(void);
  void stepper_step(uint8_t *mask, uint8_t delay_time, uint8_t dir);

  void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);// put your setup code here, to run once:
    for(byte i=in1;i<=in4;i++){
      pinMode(i,OUTPUT);}

    pinMode(13,OUTPUT); 

  }

  void loop() {
   stepper_step(stepper_masks,1,0);
    blink_pin13();  

  }

  void blink_pin13(void){
      blink_current_millis = millis();
      if(blink_current_millis - blink_start_millis >= blink_period){
      digitalWrite(13, !digitalRead(13)); 
      blink_start_millis = blink_current_millis;
    }
  }

  void stepper_step(uint8_t *mask, uint8_t delay_time, uint8_t dir){
    if (!stepper_run){
      for(byte i=6;i<10;i++){
        digitalWrite(i, 0<(mask[s]&0x80>>i-6));
      }
      if(!dir){s++;if(s>7)s=0;}
      else {s--;if(s<0)s=7;}
      stepper_start = millis();
      stepper_run = 1;
    }

    if(stepper_run){
      stepper_current = millis();
      if(stepper_current - stepper_start >= delay_time){
        stepper_run = 0;
      }    
    }
  }
```